# how to import sql file in MysqlQuery browser

Tags: mysql

I have used musqldump to create the sql file and now i am trying to use this sql file in mySqlQuery browser to get the complete database .

Here is my sql file which i have placed in mysqlquery browser ,
When i try to execute , it says :

```
       Variable 'sql_notes' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
```

here is my sqlFile.

### -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.27, for Win64 (x86)

-- Host: localhost    Database: mydb

---

-- Server version   5.5.27

```
              /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
             /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
             /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
             /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
             /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
             /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
            /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
           /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,      FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
          /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
          /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

--

### -- Current Database: `mydb`

```
            CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `mydb` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;

              USE `mydb`;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `analysismode`

```
                  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `analysismode`;
                 /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
                 /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
           CREATE TABLE `analysismode` (
          `AnalysisModeId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           `AnalysisModeDesc` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`AnalysisModeId`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
        /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `analysismode`

```
                 LOCK TABLES `analysismode` WRITE;
               /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `analysismode` DISABLE KEYS */;
               INSERT INTO `analysismode` VALUES (1,'Analyse 2050'),(2,'Analyse 2033'),       (3,'Analyse 2035'),(4,'Analyse 2044');
               /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `analysismode` ENABLE KEYS */;
                UNLOCK TABLES;



            LOCK TABLES `warranties` WRITE;
             /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `warranties` DISABLE KEYS */;
            INSERT INTO `warranties` VALUES (8,'des','ty',2,'0000-00-00',1,'2012-11-       27',0,3,4,74),(10,'desc','87',97,'0000-00-00',87,'2012-12-18',0,7,7,84),      (11,'desc','87',97,'0000-00-00',87,'2012-12-18',0,7,7,84),(12,'desc','87',97,'0000-00-       00',87,'2012-12-18',0,7,7,84),(13,'desc','87',97,'0000-00-00',87,'2012-12-18',0,7,7,84), (18,'desc','87',97,'0000-00-00',87,'2012-12-18',0,7,7,84),(19,'desc','87',97,'0000-00- 00',87,'2012-12-18',0,7,7,84),(20,'desc','87',97,'0000-00-00',87,'2012-12-18',0,7,7,84), (21,'desc','87',97,'0000-00-00',87,'2012-12-18',0,7,7,84),(22,'desc','type',11,'0000-00- 00',11,'2012-12-25',0,33,11,102),(23,'desc','wa',798,'0000-00-00',768,'2012-12- 25',0,798,789,103),(24,'DESC','786',8,'0000-00-00',8,'2012-12-25',0,88,97,104);
```

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `warranties` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

```
                      /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
                     /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
                      /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
                      /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
                       /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS  */;
                     /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
                   /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

-- Dump completed on 2012-12-09 12:23:41